# Minikube fails to pull any images in MacOS

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes

Trying to run any Pod in Minikube will fail with an `ErrImagePull` error:

```
$ kubectl get pods
utils   0/1     ErrImagePull       0          8m57s
```

Looking at the pod's logs, it shows that HTTP request timed out:

```
$ kubectl logs utils
```

shows something along the lines of:

```
kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "massenz/dnsutils:1.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

However, running the container directly from Docker works just fine:

```
$ docker run --rm -d massenz/dnsutils:1.1 sleep infinity
```

succeeds and the container can be accessed (e.g., via `exec /bin/bash`).

Answer (score 3):

This is issue is due to the fact that the "native" MacOS hypervisor VM does not have external connectivity.

This has been reported [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4589).

The fix is rather trivial, but requires installing VirtualBox first, and then using as the VM Driver:

```
$ minikube start --vm-driver virtualbox
```

After that, launching pods works just fine:

```
$ kubectl apply -f utils.yaml                
pod/utils created

$ kubectl get pods -w
NAME    READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
utils   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          5s
utils   1/1     Running             0          9s
```